# Node.js says it's using tls1.2 when minVersion set to 1.3 and connecting with a client using 1.3

Tags: node.js, ssl, tls1.3

I'm using HttpClient of .net core with with:

```
    clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    _clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback=VerifyServerCertificate;
    _clientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    _clientHandler.SslProtocols= SslProtocols.Tls13;
    HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(_clientHandler);
```

on the node side (I have node version v12.8.0) I set the server options like this:

```
    var options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('server-crt.pem'),
      ca: fs.readFileSync(config.ca),
      requestCert: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      enableTrace: true,
      minVersion: 'TLSv1.3',
      maxVersion: 'TLSv1.3'
    };
```

here's the tls trace:

```
   Received Record
Header:
  Version = TLS 1.0 (0x301)
  Content Type = Handshake (22)
  Length = 223
    ClientHello, Length=219
      client_version=0x303 (TLS 1.2)
      Random:
        gmt_unix_time=0xEEC5687E
        random_bytes (len=28): 24761EF6E5B5B89F5333E9BCF87A28E55A4B598DDB0848049                                                                                                             A66DA26
      session_id (len=0):
      cipher_suites (len=56)
        {0xC0, 0x2C} TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        {0xC0, 0x30} TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        {0x00, 0x9F} TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        {0xCC, 0xA9} TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
        {0xCC, 0xA8} TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
        {0xCC, 0xAA} TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
        {0xC0, 0x2B} TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        {0xC0, 0x2F} TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        {0x00, 0x9E} TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        {0xC0, 0x24} TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        {0xC0, 0x28} TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        {0x00, 0x6B} TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        {0xC0, 0x23} TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        {0xC0, 0x27} TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        {0x00, 0x67} TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        {0xC0, 0x0A} TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        {0xC0, 0x14} TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        {0x00, 0x39} TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        {0xC0, 0x09} TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        {0xC0, 0x13} TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        {0x00, 0x33} TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        {0x00, 0x9D} TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        {0x00, 0x9C} TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        {0x00, 0x3D} TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        {0x00, 0x3C} TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        {0x00, 0x35} TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        {0x00, 0x2F} TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        {0x00, 0xFF} TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
      compression_methods (len=1)
        No Compression (0x00)
      extensions, length = 122
        extension_type=server_name(0), length=30
          0000 - 00 1c 00 00 19 74 65 73-74 2e 61 72 74 69 73   .....test.artis
          000f - 61 6e 6d 65 64 69 63 61-6c 2e 63 6f 2e 69 6c   anmedical.co.il
        extension_type=ec_point_formats(11), length=4
          uncompressed (0)
          ansiX962_compressed_prime (1)
          ansiX962_compressed_char2 (2)
        extension_type=supported_groups(10), length=10
          ecdh_x25519 (29)
          secp256r1 (P-256) (23)
          secp521r1 (P-521) (25)
          secp384r1 (P-384) (24)
        extension_type=signature_algorithms(13), length=32
          rsa_pkcs1_sha512 (0x0601)
          dsa_sha512 (0x0602)
          ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512 (0x0603)
          rsa_pkcs1_sha384 (0x0501)
          dsa_sha384 (0x0502)
          ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384 (0x0503)
          rsa_pkcs1_sha256 (0x0401)
          dsa_sha256 (0x0402)
          ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256 (0x0403)
          rsa_pkcs1_sha224 (0x0301)
          dsa_sha224 (0x0302)
          ecdsa_sha224 (0x0303)
          rsa_pkcs1_sha1 (0x0201)
          dsa_sha1 (0x0202)
          ecdsa_sha1 (0x0203)
        extension_type=next_proto_neg(13172), length=0
        extension_type=application_layer_protocol_negotiation(16), length=14
          h2
          http/1.1
        extension_type=encrypt_then_mac(22), length=0
        extension_type=extended_master_secret(23), length=0

Sent Record
Header:
  Version = TLS 1.2 (0x303)
  Content Type = Alert (21)
  Length = 2
    Level=fatal(2), description=protocol version(70)
```

The error on the c# side is: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.

Why is node using tls1.2 when I set the minVersion to 1.3?

Comment: Can you show more of the trace? Also, what environment is the C# side running in?

Comment: This is a guess, but I suppose there's a chance that the .NET side is using TLS 1.2 even though 1.3 is specified (if on Linux with OpenSSL version before 1.1.1) and the NodeJS side falls back to TLS 1.2 in order to communicate the error to the .NET side.

Comment: The c# is running in .net core 3 on windows.  I wouldn't think node should be able to fall back to TLS 1.2 because we set the tls minVesrion to 1.3.

Comment: I tried setting the c# side to tls1.2.  The tls stack trace looks the same on the node side, but c# gets a different error: 
The response ended prematurely.

Comment: On the 7th line of your trace it shows client version is 1.2. Is that trace captured when you had c# side set to 1.3?

Comment: Yes it says 1.2 when c# is set to tls 1.3

Comment: Sounds like this is in line with what their docs say (TLS 1.3 is not yet supported in .NET Core 3 on Windows). If the client was using TLS 1.3 then it should say so in the 7th line of the trace. I believe your NodeJS server is behaving properly. It's the one rejecting the connection.

Comment: `I wouldn't think node should be able to fall back to TLS 1.2` - Node should not and it appears does not fall back to TLS 1.2 except to tell a TLS 1.3 client that it does not support TLS 1.2 (fatal protocol version error). In your trace your C# client is telling the node server that it is talking TLS 1.2. Node is configured to not support TLS 1.2 but it cannot reply in TLS 1.3 because the client did not specify TLS 1.3 so Node assumes that the client (C#) will not understand a TLS 1.3 response. So it tells C# the only way it can that it does not support TLS 1.2 - using a TLS 1.2 packet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to .NET Core 3 documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0), TLS 1.3 is not yet supported in Windows or macOS (only Linux, with OpenSSL v1.1.1 or above).

If the client was using TLS 1.3 then it should say so in the 7th line of the trace. Your NodeJS server is behaving properly. It's the one rejecting the connection because the client is actually trying to connect using TLS 1.2.

Comment: [TLS 1.3 _is supported_ in Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-11).